# About a problem with FromDigits

Tags: number-theory, digits

I have tried `FromDigits[{{1, 2, 3, 4},{2,3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}]` and the result is as expected {1234,2341,3412,4123}. However for `FromDigits[{{2,8},{8,2}}]` the result is {28000000, 28}, and not the expected {28,82}. I wonder why this is the case?

Comment: Perhaps you can gain some insight by studying the result of `{#, # /. x -> 10} &@FromDigits[{{2, 8}, {8, 2}}, x]`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me see.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation mentions (in a bullet point in "Details")

> `FromDigits[{list,n},b]` takes `n` to be an exponent [...]

I think what's happening here is that it's taking `{8,2}` to be a *list* of exponents. Indeed, it turns out that `FromDigits[{{2,8},{n,m}},b]` gives

```
{b^(-2 + n) (8 + 2 b), b^(-2 + m) (8 + 2 b)}
```

which is somewhat surprising!

I guess if your list has more than two elements, it can't match the pattern `{listofdigits, listofexponents}` (e.g. `{{__Integer},{__Integer}}`), which is probably checked first. It's a bit frustrating that it's length-dependent like that, though; I guess it's safer to use something like `FromDigits /@ listoflistsofdigits`.

Comment: Right, it's an edge case in the syntax specification, where on interpretation is used when another may have been expected.

Comment: @thorimur: Thank you very much, your method works!